# Is there a way to install SSL certificate on EC2 instances running IIS using ebextentions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a simple way to install SSL on EC2 instances running IIS without having to RDP into each server. Can it also be configured to add and install the cert upon spinning up instances during auto scaling? I have been looking around for a while, but could not find a simple way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you could build into the AMI, or you could use a configuration management system. Alternatively, you could put an ELB in front of your instances and let it handle the SSL.

Comment: I already have SSL on ELB. I also know how to create an AMI... but how can I install SSL on EC2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an AMI and include the SSL configuration in the AMI.

A better option might be to use an ELB and [AWS Certificate manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html) to terminate SSL. The ELB then talks http to your IIS servers. The SSL certificate is free from AWS for use in your ELB, but you can't use it outside the ELB. More documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html).

Comment: I already have an SSL on ELB, but I want to make the connection between ELB and EC2 instance secure, hence I need to install SSL on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Then you need to follow the advice in the first part of my answer. I can see that you would want to do that for regulatory or compliance reasons, but from a technical point of view it's likely unnecessary. AWS doesn't allow network sniffing, and they have full access to everything that isn't encrypted before it hits AWS anyway.

Comment: Do you happen to have a tutorial of how to create an AMI and include the SSL configuration in the AMI? Amazon's documentation isn't exactly clear on that

Comment: Just get a server working and create an AMI from that. There's no need for anything additional, but you'll need to recreate the AMI each time the certificate expires. Alternately you could put the certificate on S3 (with appropriate permissions) and use a startup script to download it when the server starts.